upper bound for $\int \frac{1}{|x-y|}$
Let $\alpha>0$, determine some upper bound for this integral for $x\in B_{1}$, $$\int_{B_{1}\cap B_{(1+1/\alpha)|x|}}\frac{1}{|x-y|}\,dy.$$
My approach: If $x\in B_{1}$ then $|x|\leq 1$ and $(1+1/\alpha)|x|\leq (1+1/\alpha)$, so $$\int_{B_{1}\cap B_{(1+1/\alpha)|x|}}\frac{1}{|x-y|}\,dy \leq \int_{ B_{(1+1/\alpha)|x|}}\frac{1}{|x-y|}\,dy \leq \int_{ B_{(1+1/\alpha)|x|}}\frac{1}{|x|-|y|}\,dy$$
but now, $B_{(1+1/\alpha)|x|}:=\{y\in \mathbb{R}^n: |y|\leq(1+1/\alpha)|x|\} = \{y\in \mathbb{R}^n: |y| - |x|\leq \frac{|x|}{\alpha}\}$.
Any hint will be appreciated!!

Hint: $u=y-x$. Find a ball around $x$ inside the region of integration, and the integral on that ball can be found exactly. For the rest of the region you can use maximum value times volume.

@aschepler I think the radius of this new ball is given by the minimum between $1-|x|$ and $(1+1/\alpha)|x|-|x|=1/\alpha|x|$, and what I should do with the rest of the region? thanks in advice!

@aschepler Or do you mean finding a ball centered at u, instead of x?

$y$ and $u$ aren't specific points. Only $x$ is.

Ah, oka. So the $dist_{max}(x,\partial B_{(1+1/\alpha)|x|}(0))$is given by $r=(1+1/\alpha)|x|-|x|=1/\alpha |x|$, then the ball $B_{(1/\alpha)|x|}(x)\subset B_{1}(0)\cap B_{(1+1/\alpha)|x|}(0)$

@Darek_ This integral is divergent for every $x\in B(1)$. It behaves like $|\log{x}|$...

@Medo I think you can get something like $\text{something}|x|^{2}$

@Medo that's not true if $n \ge 2$.

@Umberto P. Obviously. I am thinking of the one-dimensional case.

@aschepler Sorry, but I still have a question about how to find the integral exactly by separating the space, if you could give me some idea it would be great, thank you!

To get rid of one case, if $x$ is the zero vector of $\mathbb{R}^n$, then $B_{(1+1/\alpha)|x|} = B_0 = \{0\}$, and the integrand $\frac{1}{|0-y|}$ isn't defined for the one point in $B_1 \cap B_0 = B_0$. So there's no good answer for $x=0$. From here on, assume $x \neq 0$, so $|x|>0$.
The region $B_{(1+1/\alpha)|x|} \cap B_1$ is equal to the smaller of the two concentric balls.
So define $$R = \min\left\{\left(1+\frac 1 \alpha\right)\!|x|, 1\right\}$$
and the region of integration is $B_R$; we're looking for
$$ I = \int_{B_R} \frac{1}{|x-y|} dy $$
Note $x$ is always in this region, so the point $y=x$ makes the integral an improper integral.
For dimension $n=1$, the integral does not converge: If $-R < x < R$,
$$ I = \int_{-R}^R \frac{1}{|x-y|} dy = \int_{-R}^x \frac{1}{x-y} dy + \int_x^R \frac{1}{y-x} dy \\
I = -\lim_{y \to x^-} \ln(x-y) + \ln(x+R) + \ln(R-x) - \lim_{y \to x^+} \ln(y-x)$$
but the limits do not exist. Similarly if $x=-R$ or $x=R$, the one-sided limit does not exist.
For dimension $n \geq 2$, note the large values of integrand $\frac{1}{|x-y|}$ happen where $x$ and $y$ are close together. So consider integrating on a ball of radius $\rho > 0$ around $x$:
$$ J(\rho) = \int_{B(x,\rho)} \frac{1}{|x-y|} dy = \int_{B(0,\rho)} \frac{1}{|z|} dz $$
With a Lebesgue integral conversion,
$$ \begin{align*} J(\rho) &= \int_0^\infty \mu\!\left\{z \in B(0,\rho) \mid \frac{1}{|z|} \geq t\right\} dt \\
J(\rho) &= \int_0^{1/\rho} V_n(\rho)\, dt + \int_{1/\rho}^\infty V_n\!\left(\frac 1t \right) dt 
\end{align*} $$
where $V_n(r) = \frac{\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma\left(\frac n2 + 1\right)} r^n$ is the volume of the $n$-dimensional ball of radius $r$.
$$ J(\rho) = \int_0^{1/\rho} \rho^n V_n(1)\, dt + \int_{1/\rho}^\infty t^{-n} V_n(1)\, dt $$
$$ J(\rho) = \rho^{n-1} V_n(1) + \frac{1}{n-1}\rho^{n-1} V_n(1) = \frac{n}{n-1} \rho^{n-1} V_n(1) $$
When $y \notin B(x,\rho)$, $\frac{1}{|x-y|} < \frac 1 \rho$. Therefore
$$ \begin{align*}
I &= \int_{B_R} \frac{1}{|x-y|} dy \\
I &= \int_{B_R \cap B(x,\rho)} \frac{1}{|x-y|} dy + \int_{B_R \setminus B(x,\rho)} \frac{1}{|x-y|} dy \\
I &\leq \int_{B(x,\rho)} \frac{1}{|x-y|} dy + \int_{B_R \setminus B(x,\rho)} \frac 1 \rho dy \\
I &\leq \frac{n}{n-1} \rho^{n-1} V_n(1) + \frac 1 \rho V_n(R) \\
I &\leq \left(\frac{n}{n-1} \rho^{n-1} + \rho^{-1} R^n\right)V_n(1)
\end{align*} $$
This is true for any positive $\rho$. For one simple bound, take $\rho=R$:
$$ I \leq \frac{2n-1}{n-1} R^{n-1} V_n(1) $$
$$ I \leq \frac{(2n-1) \pi^{n/2}}{(n-1) \Gamma\!\left(\frac n2 + 1\right)} \min\left\{\left(1+ \frac 1 \alpha\right)^n |x|^n, 1\right\} $$
Or for a bound independent of $x$ and $\alpha$ (with $x \neq 0$ and $n \geq 2$),
$$ I \leq \frac{(2n-1) \pi^{n/2}}{(n-1) \Gamma\!\left(\frac n2 + 1\right)} $$

I am considering the one-dimensional case:
Let $\frac{\alpha}{1+\alpha}<|x|<1$. Then $x\in B_{1}$ and $B_{1}\cap B_{(1+{1}/{\alpha})|x|}=B_{1}$. Notice that
$$\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{dx}{|x-y|}>\int_{0}^{\frac{\alpha}{1+\alpha}}\frac{dx}{x-y}=\log{(x-\frac{\alpha}{1+\alpha})}-\log{x}.$$
You can find a similar estimate for $|x|<\frac{\alpha}{1+\alpha}$ with some modifications.
In dimensions $n\geq 2$, the integral in question equals
$$\int_{x-B_{1}\cap B_{(1+1/\alpha)|x|}}\frac{dy}{|y|},$$
which behaves like $|x|^{n-1}$. You can make that rigorous, using spherical coordinates.
